# Update Node Modules except a lot of them seem to be outdated

Tags: node.js

[My current modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCTxB.png)

[My JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08BtO.png)

I left this project too long. I have come back to it and my packages are outdated.

New to node and wanted to understand the picture

I tried npm outdated --depth=3

Updating the packages don't work. I have disabled the firewall.

What I'm doing = npm start

Results = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@14.17.3 (node-v83 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@14.17.3 (node-v83 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp
\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\sm\Desktop\Selectab
leWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --
module=C:\Users\smb\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt\li
b\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\sm\Desktop\SelectableWebApp\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.22.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN enzyme@2.9.1 requires a peer of react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN radium@0.19.6 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-day-picker@7.4.10 requires a peer of react@~0.13.x || ~0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dom@15.7.0 requires a peer of react@^15.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-resizable@1.11.1 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || 15.x || 16.x || 17.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-draggable@4.4.5 requires a peer of react-dom@>= 16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router@3.2.6 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-search@2.1.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.14.0 requires a peer of react@^16.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN semantic-ui-react@0.74.2 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 <= 15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN styled-components@4.4.1 requires a peer of react-dom@>= 16.3.0 but none is installed.

You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-10T16_25_15_569Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't enough for us to go on. We need to know in what way it does not work. What you got vs what you expected. If there's any error output for example we need that.